# Automize way of Reading file from classpath or fullpath

Tags: java, servlets

Is there are way of automatically detect whether file will be read from classpath or full path?

I want an API method do samething that done by following method (`readFile`).

there are two  generic definitions like
`classpath:filename` or `file:filename`

```
public readFile(String path){

if(path.startswith("classpath")) {

getClass().getResourceAsStream(path);

}else if(path.startswith("file")) {
// 
FileInoutStream(new File(path))
}
```

Using: Servlet 3.0

Comment: You need to set a system class path dynamically, from your java code.

Comment: for what? Did you see my question? I am trying to find a API method like readFile()

Comment: You wan't an API that *detects* if path refers to the classpath or the file system? There is no generic way that covers all loopholes. They're different concepts with *some* overlap, but still different.

Comment: you could do it by trying one, failing and trying the other `URL url = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(myFile)` and then if null, `url = ClassLoader.getSystemResource(myFile)` followed by `File file = new File(url.getURI());`